# Making requests to server with axios freezes React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get posts from a category when user clicks a button but if you click the button twice, the UI (interactive elements, navigation) freezes completely for a few seconds.

I tried removing async/await and doing it with promises, same result.

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.33:5000/',
  timeout: 3000,
});
// Action
export const getTrends = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: actions.REQUEST_TRENDS
  });
  const r = await api.post('getTrends');
  const response = r.data;
  return dispatch({
    type: actions.RECEIVE_TRENDS,
    articles: response.payload.data,
    count: response.payload.count
  });
};
```

```
// Button
            <Button
              vertical
              active={tab === 'trends'}
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ tab: 'trends' });
                this.reqTrends();
              }}
            >
              <Icon name="md-trending-up" />
              <Text>{i18n.t('TRENDING')}</Text>
            </Button>
```

```
// reqTrends
async reqTrends() {
    this.props.dispatch(getTrends());
}
```

Expected result: Data loads in background while user can still interact with other elements

Actual result: User has to wait for request to complete before using anything else

Answer (score 0):

Mutating the state is always asynchronous. Perhaps you cant try to proceed with the ajax call once the state is set by trying the following:

```
onPress={() => {
   this.setState({ tab: 'trends' }, () => this.reqTrends());
}}
```

This ensures the process flow does not over lap or production of a memory leak.

Another factor is that you should normally wrap you Async function in a try/catch block. The error could be arising inside of the function it self.

Comment: Just tried that, it still freezes. I usually wrap async functions in try/catch blocks when I'm finished with the project, as far as I can see from the console there's no errors at all.